# How to find overlapping rectangles in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, geometry, rectangles

I have a pandas dataframe that includes thousands of groups of rectangles  (group_id, x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max).

**Goal**: I want a dataframe that includes all the rectangles that intersect with at least one other rectangle in the group.

To intersect, both the y and the x have to have some overlap. I have some basic code that works, but it's too slow, and I'm not sure how to vectorize it.

```py
import pandas as pd

def find_overlapping_cuboids(df, check_z_plane=False):
    df_overlap = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
    group_ids = df["group_ID"].unique()

    for group_id in group_ids:
        df_filtered = df[df["group_ID"] == group_id]
        for i, row1 in df_filtered.iterrows():
            for j, row2 in df_filtered.iterrows():
                if i <= j:
                    continue  # Skip self-comparison
                if (
                    row1["x_min"] < row2["x_max"] and row1["x_max"] > row2["x_min"]
                ):  # Check for overlap in x direction
                    if (
                        row1["y_min"] < row2["y_max"] and row1["y_max"] > row2["y_min"]
                    ):  # Check for overlap in y direction
                        if not check_z_plane or (
                            row1["z_min"] < row2["z_max"]
                            and row1["z_max"] > row2["z_min"]
                        ):  # Check for overlap in z direction (optional)
                            df_overlap.loc[len(df_overlap)] = row1
                            df_overlap.loc[len(df_overlap)] = row2
    return df_overlap.drop_duplicates()
```

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "group_ID": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1],
        "x_min": [5, 0, 11, 4, 0, 16],
        "x_max": [15, 6, 16, 5, 4, 20],
        "y_min": [5, 0, 11, 1, 1.5, 16],
        "y_max": [15, 6, 16, 5, 4, 20],
        "z_min": [5, 0, 11, 4, 0, 16],
        "z_max": [15, 10, 16, 5, 5, 20],
    }
)

df_overlap = find_overlapping_cuboids(df_pog_full, check_z_plane=False)

print(df_overlap)
```

This is the expected output:
[image]

This is my attempt to vectorize it for just one group.  Do you have any suggestions to make this faster?

```py
def list_of_tuples_to_series(tuples, item_num):
    # this function takes a list of tuples and returns 1 series
    # the first digit in the tuple starts with item_num = 0
    # tuples = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
    # test = list_of_tuples_to_series(tuples,2)
    series = pd.Series([tuple[item_num] for tuple in tuples])
    return series


def find_overlapping_cuboids_fast(df, check_z_plane=True):
    df_overlap = pd.DataFrame(columns=["overlap_ID"] + list(df.columns))
    group_ids = df["group_ID"].unique()  # Get unique group_IDs
    overlap_id = 1  # Initialize overlap ID counter

    for group_id in group_ids:
        print(f"starting group {group_id}")
        df_filtered = df[
            df["group_ID"] == group_id
        ]  # Filter the dataframe for the current group_ID
        x_min = df_filtered["x_min"].values  # Extract the columns as NumPy arrays
        x_max = df_filtered["x_max"].values
        y_min = df_filtered["y_min"].values
        y_max = df_filtered["y_max"].values
        # Z = df_filtered['Z'].values
        # z_max = df_filtered['z_max'].values

        indices = np.arange(
            len(x_min)
        )  # Create all possible pairs of indices for comparison
        pairs = itertools.combinations(indices, 2)
        pairs = [
            pair for pair in pairs if pair[0] != pair[1]
        ]  # Exclude self-comparisons and repeated pairs
        i = list_of_tuples_to_series(pairs, 0)
        j = list_of_tuples_to_series(pairs, 1)

        overlap_x = (x_min[i] < x_max[j]) & (
            x_max[i] > x_min[j]
        )  # Check for overlap in x direction
        overlap_y = (y_min[i] < y_max[j]) & (
            y_max[i] > y_min[j]
        )  # Check for overlap in y direction
        # overlap_z = (~check_z_plane) | ((Z[i] < z_max[j]) & (z_max[i] > Z[j]))# Check for overlap in z direction (optional)
        overlap_conditions = (
            overlap_x & overlap_y
        )  # & overlap_z # Combine all overlap conditions
        overlapping_indices = np.where(overlap_conditions)[
            0
        ]  # Find the indices of overlapping cuboids

        for idx in overlapping_indices:
            row1 = df_filtered.iloc[i[idx]]
            row2 = df_filtered.iloc[j[idx]]
            row1_with_id = pd.Series(
                [overlap_id] + list(row1), index=df_overlap.columns
            )
            row2_with_id = pd.Series(
                [overlap_id] + list(row2), index=df_overlap.columns
            )
            df_overlap.loc[len(df_overlap)] = row1_with_id
            df_overlap.loc[len(df_overlap)] = row2_with_id
            overlap_id += 1  # Increment overlap ID
    return df_overlap.drop_duplicates()


# Find overlapping cuboids
df_overlap_fast2 = find_overlapping_cuboids_fast2(df, check_z_plane=False
```

Comment: Kindly provide the expected output dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [~ (invert) operator](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```py
# Prep dataframe
df = df.sort_values(by=["x_min", "x_max", "y_min", "y_max"])

# Remove rectangle with no intersections
df = df[
    ~(
        (df["x_min"] >= df["x_max"].shift(1))
        & (df["x_max"] <= df["x_min"].shift(-1).fillna(df["x_max"].max()))
    )
]

# Remove rectangles contained within others
df = df[
    ~(
        (
            (df["x_min"] >= df["x_min"].shift(-1))
            & (df["x_max"] <= df["x_max"].shift(-1))
            & (df["y_min"] >= df["y_min"].shift(-1))
            & (df["y_max"] <= df["y_max"].shift(-1))
        )
        | (
            (df["x_min"] >= df["x_min"].shift(1))
            & (df["x_max"] <= df["x_max"].shift(1))
            & (df["y_min"] >= df["y_min"].shift(1))
            & (df["y_max"] <= df["y_max"].shift(1))
        )
    )
].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output

   group_ID  x_min  x_max  y_min  y_max  z_min  z_max
0         1      0      6    0.0      6      0     10
1         1      5     15    5.0     15      5     15
2         1     11     16   11.0     16     11     16
```